# Australian payment gateway adapter for Pay API

Tags: 7, payment-gateways

Is anyone aware of a working code for the [Pay (7.x) module](http://drupal.org/project/pay) that will process payments over [eWay](http://www.eway.com.au/) or [NAB Transact](http://www.nab.com.au/wps/wcm/connect/nab/nab/home/business/4/4/5/)?

I am considering writing adapters for these gateways, but though I would put out a call for any existing code to start from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are a few modules floating around for commerce, CiviCRM and Ubercart that use eWay, they would be good basis.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I'll dig through these models for inspiration.